# Stop XCode opening GLSL files in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, file-extension

I'm quite new to OSX and I would like to prevent XCode from opening GLSL files in eclipse.

I've tried changing the default program that opens this extension files in the OS, but i can't select eclipse as an option.

Answer (score 0):

Open Eclipse > Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations

Add .glsl files and choose the default editor for this files. Text editor for example.